# JWT: 'System.String' has three segments but is not in proper JWS format

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I have an `idToken` string that is returned by google-sign-in use in mobile app with flutter and firebase:

**Code in flutter**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class Authentication {
  static GoogleSignIn googleSignIn;

  static Future<User> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User user;

    googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();

    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      );

      try {
        final UserCredential userCredential =
            await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

        user = userCredential.user;
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
          // handle the error here
        } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
          // handle the error here
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // handle the error here
      }
      print("Credential token: ${credential.token}");
      print("Credential provider id: ${credential.providerId}");
      print("AccessToken: ${googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken}");
      print("ID Token: ${googleSignInAuthentication.idToken}");
      print("AccessToken.length: ${googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken.length}");
      print("IdToken.length: ${googleSignInAuthentication.idToken.length}");

    }
    return user;
  }

  static Future signOut() async {
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

ID token is returned.

And I use this code to decode it:

```
public JwtPayload PayloadInfo(string idToken)
{
     var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(idToken);
     JwtPayload payload = jwtToken.Payload;
     return payload;
}
```

It works fine in the console app but with the .net 5 web API it fail with error:

`System.ArgumentException: IDX12739: JWT: 'System.String' has three segments but is not in proper JWS format.`

I research that my `idToken` is not in JWS type... and I don't know how to solve this.
Weirdly, the function `PayloadInfo` works fine in C# console app but in the web API, it doesn't.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost("login-google")]
[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLoginAsync(
             [FromBody] ExternalAuthModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          var result = await 
               _userService.GoogleExternalLoginAsync(model);

           if (result.IsSuccess)
           {
               return Ok(result);
           }
           return BadRequest(result);
      }

    return BadRequest("Somethings going wrong...");
}
```

**ExternalAuthModel**

```
public class ExternalAuthModel
{
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string IdToken { get; set; }
}
```

**`GoogleExternalLoginAsync` function in my Service**

```
public async Task<UserManagerResponse> GoogleExternalLoginAsync(ExternalAuthModel model)
{
    var payload = _jwtHandler.PayloadInfo(model.IdToken);
    
    if (payload is null)
    {
        return new UserManagerResponse
        {
            Message = "Invalid google authentication.",
            IsSuccess = false
        };
    }

    var info = new UserLoginInfo(model.Provider, payload.Sub, model.Provider);
    var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);

    if (user is null)
    {

        user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(payload["email"].ToString());
        await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);

        if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.User))
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.User));

        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.User);
        await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
    }
    else
    {
        await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
    }

    if (user is null)
    {
        return new UserManagerResponse
        {
            Message = "Invalid google authentication.",
            IsSuccess = false
        };
    }

    var token = await _jwtHandler.GenerateToken(user);
    return new UserManagerResponse
    {
        Message = token[0],
        IsSuccess = true,
        ExpireDate = DateTime.Parse(token[1])
    };

}
```

**`PayloadInfo` function**

```
public JwtPayload PayloadInfo(string idToken)
{
    // Exception when excute this line... it says my idToken is not in 
    // JWS compact format....
    var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(idToken); 
    JwtPayload payload = jwtToken.Payload;
    return payload;
}
```

**Log...**

```
2021-07-04T16:10:30.3810628+07:00  [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. (48a46595)
System.ArgumentException: IDX12739: JWT: 'System.String' has three segments but is not in proper JWS format.
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken..ctor(String jwtEncodedString)
   at FTask.AuthServices.Helpers.JwtHandler.PayloadInfo(String idToken) in D:\cn7\Project\hao\ftask\FTask.AuthServices\Helpers\JwtHandler.cs:line 83
   at FTask.AuthServices.Services.UserService.GoogleExternalLoginAsync(ExternalAuthModel model) in D:\cn7\Project\hao\ftask\FTask.AuthServices\Services\UserService.cs:line 163
   at FTask.Api.Controllers.AuthController.GoogleLoginAsync(ExternalAuthModel model) in D:\cn7\Project\hao\ftask\FTask.Api\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 109
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: you may check your token by using https://jwt.io/ url

Comment: it is working for me, in .Net 5 Web Api, there were no problems ))

Comment: You should know that the token exposes your private personal info (email, name) and you might want to remove it.

Comment: I check in jwt.io first then I implement that...but in the console app, it works so smooth....when I bring it in web API it throws an exception...

Comment: I would add some logging to check you're actually getting the string properly just before you decode it. (It would help if you'd show the full stack trace rather than just the message - we can't tell where it's actually failing at the moment.) The error message is *slightly* suggestive that what's being received is the text "System.String" rather than the JWT.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added a log for it....Thanks for your comment...

Comment: Right - looking at the code, it does look like the value of `idToken` is just `"System.String"`. So you need to trace through how that's propagating.

Comment: @MansurKurtov I don't know....why in the console app it works...but in web API it doesn't work... I am crazy about it for a few days....

Comment: Check your installation, may be problem in .Net 5 installation, because there are no any error in your code

Comment: @MansurKurtov all of the different APIs is still work well... and I have reset my laptop and reinstall VisualStudio 1 month ago... another projects work well too...

Comment: So have you looked in the debugger to check the model you're receiving? Have you done anything to check what the HTTP request looks like?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks you, I have a solution and it works,... and before post this problem I try to debug it many times... Because no hope so I post to ask... Thanks all, I have my solution for this... thanks all

Comment: @Hao: So when you were debugging, did `idToken` show the actual value? Because as I said, it *looks* like the problem is in getting the model to your code in the first place... in which case the answer you've accepted wouldn't help (and might give false hope to anyone else seeing this question). Please edit your question to show the results of your debugging, and in particular whether you managed to observe the right value of `idToken` in your `PayloadInfo` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please test this:

```
       public JwtPayload GetPayload()
        {
            var token = "<your token>";
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenData = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
            return tokenData.Payload;
        }
```

i tested your token in .Net 5 Web API and got this result:

[image: decoded jwt]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to trim whitespace from token string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).